# How to check if value already exists in database with c# for unity (error in SQL syntax)

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get if a value already exists in my database for a registration and I've searched everywhere for an answer but I get this error:

> " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near...at line 1".

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

```
void Start()
{
    linhaConn = "Server=localhost;" +
        "Database=jogo;" +
        "User ID=root;" +
        "Password=;" +
        "Pooling=false;" +
        "CharSet=utf8";
    ConnDatabase(linhaConn);

}

void ConnDatabase(string lConn)
{
    conn = new MySqlConnection(lConn);
    conn.Open();
    
    print("Conectado"); 
}

public void InserirDB()
{   
    ConnDatabase(linhaConn);
    txtUser = InpUserCriar.text;
    txtEmail = InpEmail.text;

    command = new MySqlCommand("select * from jogador where ([email] = '" + txtEmail + "')", conn);
    int UserExist = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

    if (UserExist > 0)
    {
        print("already exists");
    }
    else
    {
        print("doesnt exists");
    }

    conn.Close();
```

EDIT
I did it! Here is the code:

```
   ConnDatabase(linhaConn);
    txtUser = InpUserCriar.text;
    txtEmail = InpEmail.text;

    string countDataEmail;
    command = new MySqlCommand("select count(*) from jogador where email= '" + txtEmail+ "' ;", conn);
    countDataEmail = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    if (countDataEmail == "0")
    {
        print("it doesnt exist");
    }
    else
    {
        print("email already exists");
    }
```

Comment: `select *` is not going to return an `int`, it's going to return all rows and columns which match your `where` clause. If you want an integer, you could do `select COUNT(*)`

Comment: @RyanWilson I did that and it continues to show the error...

Comment: What is the value of your variable, `txtEmail`? Also, you should look into using `parameterized` queries.

Comment: Two things:  Ryan Wilson is right that building SQL like this should always be avoided because it's not secure.  Also, when you're just trying to figure out if something exists, it's more efficient to do `SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM myTable WHERE .....`

Comment: @RyanWilson it's a string

Comment: @BeatrizMorais I know it's a string, I'm asking what is the value of that string when you receive the exception.

Comment: @trademark I did that too and didn't work

Comment: @RyanWilson its the text from an input field in unity. When I write the username and email address and click on a button, I'm trying that if that email already exists it doesn't let you register

Comment: I'd recommend taking out the cast to an int and then use the debugger to see what exactly ExecuteScalar is returning.  It may not be something that casts to an integer.

Comment: @BeatrizMorais You still haven't answered my question: "What is the value?" I don't need to know where it comes from or that it's a string. ie. `txtEmail` = ???

Comment: `[email]` is not valid MariaDB syntax. Drop the square brackets and the parentheses and just write `WHERE email = @email` (and use a parameter).

Comment: The error is in the line "int UserExist = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();"

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if they query returns ant row you can use UserExist.HasRows

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention [**SQL Injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! Whenever dealing with User Input make sure they can't harm or retrieve something from your database. See the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) which uses a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to avoid that.

---

besides that, are you sure it should be

```
... where ([email] = some@email.address)
```

instead of (how I know SQL queries)

```
... where email = some@email.adddres;
```

---

So together it would probably be something like

```
command = new MySqlCommand("select * from jogador where email = @email;", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail);
commandPrepare();
```